# How to “adb connect” to Samsung Galaxy Tab (P3100)?

Tags: adb

I am trying to connect to my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab P3100) through network.

```
 > adb connect 10.0.0.2
 unable to connect to 10.0.0.2:5555

 > adb connect 10.0.0.2:5555
 unable to connect to 10.0.0.2:5555:5555

 > adb connect 10.0.0.2:5038
 unable to connect to 10.0.0.2:5038:5038
```

Ping works successfully. I also checked "USB debugging" option in "Developers options" on tablet.

Connection throught USB ("adb usb") works fine.

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

you have to tell adb to use tcpip

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 10.0.0.2
```

then to go back to usb mode

```
adb usb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless) (adbWireless) and connect to it via wireless, using the wifi without the cable you can connect directly via a address as shown by the widget/app.

Usually its the following:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.x:5555
```